# How to trigger action in ChildWidgetA from sibling ChildWidgetB

Tags: flutter, dart

**NOTE**:
I ended up restructuring things instead, eliminating the sibling-communication path.

```
ParentWidget
 |-ChildWidgetA
   |-ChildWidgetB
```

Because I needed two different versions of ChildWidgetA (one static, one with editing fields), and because I needed bi-directional communication (sibling B sends command to A, A returns final status back to B)...

It all just got two complicated. Made the "sibling" node a child instead, making communication easier.

Lesson: if you need sibling-to-sibling communication, try hard to find a way to make them parent/child instead. Sibling-to-sibling widget communication is possible but makes code very hard to follow due to very indirect code flow.

**--------- Original Post -----------**

**Situation**: Parent widget, with two children.

As:

```
ParentWidget
 |-ChildWidgetA
 |-ChildWidgetB
```

ChildWidgetA contains a data entry form.
ChildWidgetB contains buttons (save, cancel, export, etc)

**Need** action (button click) in ChildWidgetB to trigger response (read and save of text data) in ChildWidgetA.

Changing parent/child relationships like this:

```
ParentWidget
 |-ChildWidgetA
    |-ChildWidgetB
```

... would work (so child could use callback provided by parent) but is not a possibility in my actual situation, unless there's no other possible solution.

I'd also rather **not** pull knowledge of the data entry form up into the (unrelated) ParentWidget by, for example, creating `TextEditingController` objects there for to help the ControlsWidget read text values for save.

**Question:** What possibilities exist to get this to work if I alter/rearrange the code? (Perhaps streams, event listeners, state magic...?)

Here's some annotated example code that demonstrates the structural issue:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column( 
      children: [
        DataEntryFormWidget(),           // TextFields with values to read, save
        ControlsWidgetWithSaveButton(),  // Button I want to trigger the save
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DataEntryFormWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(), // assume I have a way to read values from these
        TextFormField(),
        // etc
      ]
    );
  }

  void doSave() {
    // read values from TextFormField()
    //    This is the thing I cannot do from ControlsWidgetWithSaveButton
    //    because that doesn't have access to TextFormField(s)... 
    //    So can't simply move this code/function to controls widget.
    // 
    // getDatabase.save(... the values ...)  
    // (all saved ok)
  }
}


class ControlsWidgetWithSaveButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // THE PROBLEM:
            // Here I want to invoke/trigger the doSave() function.
            // Could do the DB write here if I had the data... 
          },
          child: const Text('Save'),
        ),
        // ...  <assume some other buttons> 
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package. Similarly you can do it with other state management packages but this is the easiest one.

First, we need to create a `ChangeNotifier`, the `save` method will be used to notify the listeners that save was requested.

```
class FormController extends ChangeNotifier {
  void save() {
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

change your `ParentWidget` to register the provider

```
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => FormController(),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          DataEntryFormWidget(), // TextFields with values to read, save
          ControlsWidgetWithSaveButton(), // Button I want to trigger the save
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You need to convert your `DataEntryFormWidget` to a `StatefulWidget` because we need to handle the `initState`  and `dispose`. In the `initState` we will add a listener that calls our `doSave` method and inside `dispose` we will remove the listener.

```
class DataEntryFormWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<DataEntryFormWidget> createState() => _DataEntryFormWidgetState();
}

class _DataEntryFormWidgetState extends State<DataEntryFormWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<FormController>(context, listen: false).addListener(doSave);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    Provider.of<FormController>(context, listen: false).removeListener(doSave);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      TextFormField(),
      TextFormField(),
    ]);
  }

  void doSave() {
    // save
  }
}
```

Finally, in the `ControlsWidgetWithSaveButton` widget, inside the `onPressed` method, we are calling the `save` to notify the listeners.

```
class ControlsWidgetWithSaveButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Provider.of<FormController>(context, listen: false).save();
        },
        child: const Text('Save'),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I can see how that works. I've used Provider/Consumer as a wrapper for Inherited Widget, but not used it in this way. Essentially creating a shared message board object where one widget posts a note, and the board immediately notifies another widget that the post happened... and it in turn responds to that notification by taking an action. Interesting. Looking for implications for widget recomposition triggers, doesn't look like there are any (which is good).

Comment: Attempted to use this, but had problems because DataEntryFormWidget save action triggers a replacement of itself with StaticFormDisplayWidget. This caused issues in dispose() ...removeListener() : "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe".  Solved by caching FormController instance lookup in "late FormController formController;" var, setting that in initState(), using it in problem .removeListener call in dispose().  By the time dispose() activates, it's disconnected enough that it can't look up object from Provider.

Comment: Also discovered there's an issue with "can't cancel action", no way for save to cancel (validation errors) and communicate "was cancelled" back up the path to tell triggering button to not assume save completed and change it's label/icon. Marking as accepted answer, because it works; but turns out I have a more complex situation than I described as my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GlobalKey and then call methods in other
components.

`GlobalKey<ComponentsBState> componentsBStateGlobalKey = GlobalKey()`.

Attention should be paid to deleting '_' when declaring, Make it a state class that can be accessed externally.

Like this:

`class ComponentsBState extends State<ComponentsB> {}`

Comment: I considered this, but this approach feels a bit hack-ish to me, though I know it's popular. The Keys system is intended for use in identifying widgets for the recomposition engine, primarily, to fix bugs that can otherwise happen when moving widgets and elements in the composition trees. Using it as a backhanded handle to make a widget "global" and addressable from anywhere as a coding technique feels like an unintended consequence of the Key classes rather than an intentional feature. Concerns me about future stability of this as a mechanism. I agree your solution is valid and works, tho.

Comment: Note: I think I'll end up having to use this, because of a complexity that wasn't part of my question: I need info about final status to flow back up the call chain [invoking button needs to get info back about the result of the function]. Using global key to grab handle to target state object and invoke function that way seems to be the only way to get a return value out of function and back to button.  Thank you for the assistance.  It's maybe not the best solution to my posted problem, but turns out it is the best solution to a more complex problem!

Comment: If you don't want to use the GlobalKey method, you can also use the Provider or manually write a tool class method in the publish subscribe mode to achieve this function